# How to bind Command to ios table section header click?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

How can I bind Command to recieve taps on sections of my Table? I am using MvxViewController with custom TableSource, but it seems that I cant add bindings to my VM when creating UIView for sections.

Here is my ViewModel:

```
public class TestViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> _sections;
    public ObservableCollection<string> Sections
    {
        get { return _sections; }
        set { _sections = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Sections); }
    }


    private MvxCommand _sectionTappedCommand;
    public ICommand SectionTappedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            _sectionTappedCommand = _sectionTappedCommand ?? new MvxCommand(DoSectionTappedCommand);
            return _sectionTappedCommand;
        }
    }
    private void DoSectionTappedCommand()
    {
        //I want this command somehow to be called when user taps section header
        Debug.WriteLine("Section tapped!");        
    }
}
```

My view:

```
[Register("TestView")]
public class OrderView : MvxViewController
{
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        View = new UIView() { BackgroundColor = UIColor.White };
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        var table = new UITableView(new RectangleF(0, 20, 320, 660));
        Add(table);

        var source = new TestTableSource(table);
        table.Source = source;

        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<OrderView, OrderViewModel>();
        // I think here I need to write something like:
        // set.Bind(source).For(s => s.Section.TapAction).To(vm => vm.SectionTappedCommand);**
        set.Bind(source).For(s => s.ItemsSource).To(vm => vm.Sections).OneWay();
        set.Apply();

    }
}
```

Table source:

```
public class TestTableSource : MvxBaseTableViewSource
{
    // all needed overrides implemented
    private IList<OrderGuest> _sections;
    public IList<OrderGuest> ItemsSource
    {
        get
        {
            return _sections;
        }
        set
        {
            _sections = value;
            ReloadTableData();
        }
    }
    public override UIView GetViewForHeader(UITableView tableView, int section)
    {
        // Do I need to add bindings here?
        var view = new OrderGuestSectionHeader(OrderGuestSectionHeader(tableView, section), () => {
            Debug.WriteLine("selected " + section.ToString());
        });
        return view;
    }

    public override int NumberOfSections(UITableView tableView)
    {
        if (_sections == null)
            return 0;

        return _sections.Count;
    }

    public override string[] SectionIndexTitles(UITableView tableView)
    {
        if (_sections == null)
            return null;

        return _sections.Select(x => x.Name).ToArray();
    }

}
```

Subclassed UIView for section header:

```
public sealed class OrderGuestSectionHeader : UIView
{
    private UIButton SectionButton;
    public Action TapAction;

    public OrderGuestSectionHeader(string header, Action tapped)
    {
        Frame = new RectangleF(0, 0, 320, 20);
        BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;
        SectionButton = new UIButton(this.Frame);
        SectionButton.TouchUpInside += SectionButton_TouchUpInside;
        SectionButton.Title(header);
        TapAction = tapped;
        Add(SectionButton);
    }

    private void SectionButton_TouchUpInside(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TapAction();
    }
}
```

Comment: It might help if you can add more detail to this question - e.g. some detail about what your CustomSource is doing to create these section headers might help; or perhaps some detail about what "it seems that" means - if you've already tried several things, then let us know what they are and how they failed. @JonSkeet has some great tips on writing questions that help people provide answers http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: Hi Stuart! I've added sample code with comments. Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways you could achieve this effect.

For just your current requirements, the easiest way to achieve it would be to add just a single command to the `TestTableSource` and to have that command passed on to your section header inside the Action handler.

```
public class TestTableSource : MvxBaseTableViewSource
{
    public ICommand FooCommand { get; set; }

    // existing code

    public override UIView GetViewForHeader(UITableView tableView, int section)
    {
        var view = new OrderGuestSectionHeader(OrderGuestSectionHeader(tableView, section), () => {
            Debug.WriteLine("selected " + section.ToString());
            if (FooCommand != null) FooCommand.Execute(null);
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

This Command can then be bound to the ViewModel by adding the `OrderView` binding:

```
set.Bind(source)
   .For(s => s.FooCommand)
   .To(vm => vm.SectionTappedCommand)
   .OneWay();
```

---

If you wanted to go further - if you wanted to do a more complicated binding - then you could actually set up a full binding `DataContext` for the Header View. The easiest way to do this would be to inherit from `MvxView`. I won't go into the full detail of this here - instead for an introduction to `MvxView`, see the N+1 video - http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/n32-truth-about-viewmodels-starring.html with sample source code in https://github.com/slodge/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/tree/master/N-32-ViewModels

Comment: excuse me Stuart can you please tell me where i have to bind the ICommand (FooCommand) ?